# How to migrate the content with images from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 for single content type automatically?

Tags: image, drupal, migration, drupal-8, data-migration

How to migrate the content with images from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 for single content type automatically (using Drush command)?

Comment: no automatic way that I know of. Migrate module or custom code are probably options though.